# Chrome showing a break in the Bootstrap 3.0 Navbar (VERY intermittent)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

OK here is my issue - ever so often 10 or 20 loads of the page, from various menu options Google Chrome stutters on the Bootstrap Navbar.  What happens is that the navbar drops into the live page and it appears that Chrome threw a break into the Bootstrap Navbar.  At first i thought it might be the iframe that i have in script, but even after removing that it still shows up.  Again this is VERY intermittent, but enough to bug some Chrome users.  I have scoured the dev tools to find out what is causing it to no avail.

you can view the code at www.murphyschphouse.com/contactus.html and also the resform.html - although not as much on that page (maybe ever 50 loads or so) - and they are pretty much identical in code.  I.E. handles it just fine - usually it is the other way around - go figure ... Any help to solve this would be greatly appreciated.  I have written a JavaScript script that reloads the page and this seems to solve it, but I think I would rather have a CSS fix rather than a JavaScript hack. HELP

Comment: Include relevant code to the question, please. Also, make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) if possible.

Comment: I believe I fixed it - I will keep you updated - had to do with the header, once I copied from one that was working properly and it seems to have fixed it.